# Extract a regular expression match

Tags: regex, r

I'm trying to extract a number from a string.

And do something like `[0-9]+` on the string `"aaa12xxx"` and get `"12"`.

I thought it would be something like:

```
> grep("[0-9]+", "aaa12xxx", value=TRUE)
[1] "aaa12xxx"
```

And then I figured...

```
> sub("[0-9]+", "\\1", "aaa12xxx")
[1] "aaaxxx"
```

But I got some form of response doing:

```
> sub("[0-9]+", "ARGH!", "aaa12xxx")
[1] "aaaARGH!xxx"
```

There's a small detail I'm missing.

Answer (score 190, accepted):

Use the new stringr package which wraps all the existing regular expression operates in a consistent syntax and adds a few that are missing:

```
library(stringr)
str_locate("aaa12xxx", "[0-9]+")
#      start end
# [1,]     4   5
str_extract("aaa12xxx", "[0-9]+")
# [1] "12"
```

Comment: (almost) exactly what I needed, but as I started typing in `?str_extract` I saw `str_extract_all` and life was good again.

Answer (score 126):

It is probably a bit hasty to say '*ignore the standard functions*' - the help file for `?gsub` even specifically references in 'See also':

> ‘regmatches’ for extracting matched substrings based on the results of
>   ‘regexpr’, ‘gregexpr’ and ‘regexec’.

So this will work, and is fairly simple:

```
txt <- "aaa12xxx"
regmatches(txt,regexpr("[0-9]+",txt))
#[1] "12"
```

Comment: How do you extract multiple groups? For example, extract separately 12 and 15 from the string "aaa12bbb15ccc" ?

Comment: @DuccioA - `regmatches(x, gregexpr("[0-9]+", x))` - like `sub` is for one replacement, and `gsub` is for all replacements, `regexpr` finds one result, while `gregexpr` finds all results.

Answer (score 31):

For your specific case you could remove all not numbers:

```
gsub("[^0-9]", "", "aaa12xxxx")
# [1] "12"
```

It won't work in more complex cases

```
gsub("[^0-9]", "", "aaa12xxxx34")
# [1] "1234"
```

Comment: Not the best option for extracting a target from a string. This is good for just returning any digits in a string that may or may not be together by removing all characters that are not digits and could create misses if you think it extracts (e.g., gsub("[^0-9]", "", "aaa12xx1xx" returns 121 instead what might be expected c(12, 1))

Comment: @daneshjai This is exacly what OP wants. It is not generalized sollution.

Comment: Not necessarily. The title of the question is "Extract a regular expression match". It fits the example, but it may give the wrong impression and in some instances contrary results. So I think it's helping for others that end up landing here and may be new to regex to clarify that this is deleting all characters and not a pattern to extract a target.

Comment: @daneshjai Most of answers returns 12 for  "aaa12xx1xx" which is not what you expect.

Answer (score 17):

You can use PERL regexs' lazy matching:

```
> sub(".*?([0-9]+).*", "\\1", "aaa12xx99",perl=TRUE)
[1] "12"
```

Trying to substitute out non-digits will lead to an error in this case.

Comment: Do not need PERL if you are willing to use the slightly uglier "[^0-9]*([0-9]+).*"

Answer (score 6):

Use capturing parentheses in the regular expression and group references in the replacement. Anything in parentheses gets remembered. Then they're accessed by \2, the first item. The first backslash escapes the backslash's interpretation in R so that it gets passed to the regular expression parser.

```
gsub('([[:alpha:]]+)([0-9]+)([[:alpha:]]+)', '\\2', "aaa12xxx")
```

Answer (score 5):

One way would be this:

```
test <- regexpr("[0-9]+","aaa12456xxx")
```

Now, notice regexpr gives you the starting and ending indices of the string:

```
    > test
[1] 4
attr(,"match.length")
[1] 5
```

So you can use that info with substr function

```
substr("aaa12456xxx",test,test+attr(test,"match.length")-1)
```

I'm sure there is a more elegant way to do this, but this was the fastest way I could find. Alternatively, you can use sub/gsub to strip out what you don't want to leave what you do want.

Answer (score 4):

One important difference between these approaches the the behaviour with any non-matches. For example, the regmatches method may not return a string of the same length as the input if there is not a match in all positions

```
> txt <- c("aaa12xxx","xyz")

> regmatches(txt,regexpr("[0-9]+",txt)) # could cause problems

[1] "12"

> gsub("[^0-9]", "", txt)

[1] "12" ""  

> str_extract(txt, "[0-9]+")

[1] "12" NA
```

Answer (score 3):

A solution for this question

```
library(stringr)
str_extract_all("aaa12xxx", regex("[[:digit:]]{1,}"))
# [[1]]
# [1] "12"
```

**[[:digit:]]**: digit [0-9]

**{1,}**: Matches at least 1 times

Answer (score 2):

Using strapply in the gsubfn package.  strapply is like apply in that the args are object, modifier and function except that the object is a vector of strings (rather than an array) and the modifier is a regular expression (rather than a margin):

```
library(gsubfn)
x <- c("xy13", "ab 12 cd 34 xy")
strapply(x, "\\d+", as.numeric)
# list(13, c(12, 34))
```

This says to match one or more digits (\d+) in each component of x passing each match through as.numeric.  It returns a list whose components are vectors of matches of respective components of x.   Looking the at output we see that the first component of x has one match which is 13 and the second component of x has two matches which are 12 and 34.  See http://gsubfn.googlecode.com for more info.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution:

```
temp = regexpr('\\d', "aaa12xxx");
substr("aaa12xxx", temp[1], temp[1]+attr(temp,"match.length")[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the package *unglue* we would do the following:

```r
# install.packages("unglue")
library(unglue)
unglue_vec(c("aaa12xxx", "aaaARGH!xxx"), "{prefix}{number=\\d+}{suffix}", var = "number")
#> [1] "12" NA
```

<sup>Created on 2019-11-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Use the `convert` argument to convert to a number automatically :

```
unglue_vec(
  c("aaa12xxx", "aaaARGH!xxx"), 
  "{prefix}{number=\\d+}{suffix}", 
  var = "number", 
  convert = TRUE)
#> [1] 12 NA
```

Answer (score 0):

While you said, you want to extract `"12"` from `"aaa12xxx"`, it seems that you actually want `12`. In such cases, `strcapture` from the preinstalled `utils` package is a very safe & powerful solution:

```r
strcapture(pattern = "[^\\d]*(\\d+)[^\\d]*", x = "aaa12xxx", proto = list(my_val = integer()), perl = TRUE)
#>   my_val
#> 1     12
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: In contrast to `stringi`/`stringr` based solutions it allows you to use the more powerful `PCRE `.

Answer (score -3):

You could write your regex functions with C++, compile them into a DLL and call them from R.

```
    #include <regex>

    extern "C" {
    __declspec(dllexport)
    void regex_match( const char **first, char **regexStr, int *_bool)
    {
        std::cmatch _cmatch;
        const char *last = *first + strlen(*first);
        std::regex rx(*regexStr);
        bool found = false;
        found = std::regex_match(*first,last,_cmatch, rx);
        *_bool = found;
    }

__declspec(dllexport)
void regex_search_results( const char **str, const char **regexStr, int *N, char **out )
{
    std::string s(*str);
    std::regex rgx(*regexStr);
    std::smatch m;

    int i=0;
    while(std::regex_search(s,m,rgx) && i < *N) {
        strcpy(out[i],m[0].str().c_str());
        i++;
        s = m.suffix().str();
    }
}
    };
```

call in R as

```
dyn.load("C:\\YourPath\\RegTest.dll")
regex_match <- function(str,regstr) {
.C("regex_match",x=as.character(str),y=as.character(regstr),z=as.logical(1))$z }

regex_match("abc","a(b)c")

regex_search_results <- function(x,y,n) {
.C("regex_search_results",x=as.character(x),y=as.character(y),i=as.integer(n),z=character(n))$z }

regex_search_results("aaa12aa34xxx", "[0-9]+", 5)
```

Comment: This is completely unnecessary. See the answers of "thelatemail" or "Robert" for an easy solution inside R.