# R - Using grep and gsub to return more than one match in the same (character) vector element

Tags: r, regex

Imagine we want to find all of the FOOs and subsequent numbers in the string below and return them as a vector (apologies for unreadability, I wanted to make the point there is no regular pattern before and after the FOOs):

```
xx <- "xasdrFOO1921ddjadFOO1234dakaFOO12345ndlslsFOO1643xasdf"
```

We can use this to find one of them (taken from [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2969315/rhow-to-get-grep-to-return-the-match-rather-than-the-whole-string))

```
gsub(".*(FOO[0-9]+).*", "\\1", xx)
[1] "FOO1643"
```

However, I want to return all of them, as a vector.

I've thought of a complicated way to do it using strplit() and gregexpr() - but I feel there is a better (and easier) way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may be interested in `regmatches`:

```
> regmatches(xx, gregexpr("FOO[0-9]+", xx))[[1]]
[1] "FOO1921"  "FOO1234"  "FOO12345" "FOO1643"
```

Comment: Perfect, I didn't realise there was anything "built in". I should have read the help page for grep more closely though, I would have found this myself! -1 for me

Answer (score 3):

```
xx <- "xasdrFOO1921ddjadFOO1234dakaFOO12345ndlslsFOO1643xasdf"
library(stringr)
str_extract_all(xx, "(FOO[0-9]+)")[[1]]
#[1] "FOO1921"  "FOO1234"  "FOO12345" "FOO1643"
```

this can take vectors of strings as well, and mathces will be in list elements.

Answer (score 2):

Slightly shorter version.

```
library(gsubfn)
strapplyc(xx,"FOO[0-9]*")[[1]]
```