# R: How to extract specific digits from a string?

Tags: r, regex

I want to retrieve the first Numbers (here -> 344002) from a string:

```
string <- '<a href="/Archiv-Suche/!344002&amp;s=&amp;SuchRahmen=Print/" ratiourl-ressource="344002"'
```

I am preferably looking for a regular expression, which looks for the Numbers after the ! and before the &amp.

All I came up with is this but this catches the ! as well (!344002):

```
regmatches(string, gregexpr("\\!([[:digit:]]+)", string, perl =TRUE))
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `sub('.*?!(\\d+)&.*', '\\1', string)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/j06PAb/2):

```
(?<=\!)\d+(?=&amp)
```

Use this code:

```
regmatches(string, gregexpr("(?<=\!)\d+(?=&amp)", string, perl=TRUE))
```

- `(?<=\!)` is a lookbehind, the match will start following `!`
- `\d+` matches one digit or more
- `(?=&amp)` stops the match if next characters are `&amp`

Comment: You need to double escape like \\d+ and I don't think you need to escape the ! at all `regmatches(string, gregexpr("(?<=!)\\d+(?=&amp)", string, perl=TRUE))` for instance. But +1.

Comment: Thank you for the quick help!

Answer (score 0):

```
library(gsubfn)
strapplyc(string, "!(\\d+)")[[1]]
```

---

Old answer]

Test this code.

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(string, "[0-9]+")
```

similar question&answer is present here

[Extract a regular expression match in R version 2.10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192316/extract-a-regular-expression-match-in-r-version-2-10)

Comment: this doesnt guarantee you get the digits after the ! and before the &

Answer (score 0):

You may *capture* the digits (`\d+`) in between `!` and `&amp` and get it with `regexec`/`regmatches`:

```
> string <- '<a href="/Archiv-Suche/!344002&amp;s=&amp;SuchRahmen=Print/" ratiourl-ressource="344002"'
> pattern = "!(\\d+)&amp;"
> res <- unlist(regmatches(string,regexec(pattern,string)))
> res[2]
[1] "344002"
```

See the [online R demo](http://ideone.com/AjKtYk)