# Ignore last "/" in R regex

Tags: r, regex

Given the string `"http://compras.dados.gov.br/materiais/v1/materiais.html?pdm=08275/"`, I need to generate a regex filter so that it ignores the last char if it is an "/" .

I tried the following regex `"(http:////)?compras\\.dados\\.gov\\.br.*\\?.*(?<!//)"`  as of [regexr.com/4om61](http://regexr.com/4om61), but it doesn´t work when I run in R as:

```
regex_exp_R   <- "(http:////)?compras\\.dados\\.gov\\.br.*\\?.*(?<!//)"
grep(regex_exp_R, "http://compras.dados.gov.br/materiais/v1/materiais.html?pdm=08275/", perl = T, value = T)
```

I need this to work in pure regex and grep function, without using any string R package.
Thank you.

**Simplified Case:**
After important contributions of you all, one last issue remains. 
Because I will use regex as an input in another friunction, the solution ***must work with pure regex and grep***.

The remaining point is a very basic one: given the strings "a1bc/" or "a1bc", the regex must return "a1bc". Building on suggestions I received, I tried

`grep(".*[^//]" ,"a1bc/", perl = T, value = T)`, but still get "a1bc/" instead of "a1bc". Any hints? Thank you.

Comment: Use this as regex: `(?:http://)?compras\.dados\.gov\.br.*\?[^/]*` There is no need to use lookbehind here.

Comment: `gsub('/$', '', x)` will make a copy of `x` without the `/` at the end (if there is one for the given element of `x`)

Comment: I am not completely clear on what you are looking for--what do you mean by ignore? Do you want it returned without the last `/` or do you want it to be an optional element of your search pattern.

Comment: Dear Andrew, I want the string returned without the last "/". Thank you

Comment: @FabioCorrea: Did you try my suggested regex?

Comment: @anubhava, yes, it did not work. Simplifying the problem and building on your proposed solution, when I try grep(".*[^//]" ,"abc/", perl = T, value = T), I get "abc/" instead of "abc". Thank you.

Comment: With `grep()`, even if you correctly match part of the string, it will return the original string regardless. E.g., `grep("a", "abc", value = T)`

Comment: @FabioCorrea: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23901600/548225

Comment: Just `grep` the `gsub("/+$", "", x)`

Comment: I edited the original question for a simplified last issue, after all contributions. Thank you.

Comment: @FabioCorrea, it cannot work with only `grep()` because `grep()` is not designed to return partial matches. It is designed to return an index--`grep("c", letters)`--but it can return the value of the original string instead of the index--`grep("c", letters, value = T)`. I would suggest using another base function such as `gsub` (on its own, or with `grep`). Read the value header in `?grep`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return the string without the last `/` you can do this several ways. Below are a couple options using base R:

Using a back-reference in `gsub()` (`sub()` would work too here):

```
gsub("(.*?)/*$", "\\1", x)
[1] "http://compras.dados.gov.br/materiais/v1/materiais.html?pdm=08275"

# or, adapting your original pattern
gsub("((http:////)?compras\\.dados\\.gov\\.br.*\\?.*?)/*$", "\\1", x)
[1] "http://compras.dados.gov.br/materiais/v1/materiais.html?pdm=08275"
```

By position using `ifelse()` and `substr()` (this will proabbly be a little bit faster if scaling matters)

```
ifelse(substr(x, nchar(x), nchar(x)) == "/", substr(x, 1, nchar(x)-1), x)
[1] "http://compras.dados.gov.br/materiais/v1/materiais.html?pdm=08275"
```

**Data**:

```
x <- "http://compras.dados.gov.br/materiais/v1/materiais.html?pdm=08275/"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `sub` to remove a trailing `/`:

```
x <- c("a1bc/", "a2bc")
sub("/$", "", x)
```

This changes nothing on a string that does not end in `/`.

As others have pointed out, `grep` does not modify strings. It returns a numeric vector of indices of the matched strings or a vector of the (unmodified) matched items. It's usually used to subset a character vector.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a negative look-behind at the end to ensure it doesn't end with the character you don't want (in this case, a `/`). The regex would then be:

```
.+(?<!\/)
```

You can view it here with your three input examples: https://regex101.com/r/XB9f7K/1/. If you only want it to match urls, then you would change the `.+` part at the beginning to your url regex.

Answer (score -1):

How about trying `gsub("(.*?)/+$","\\1",s)`?