# R Regex to capture groups and refer to captured pattern

Tags: r, regex, string, gsub

When writing regular expressions with R's `gsub()` function I thought that I could use capture groups by enclosing patterns in `(...)`, and referring to the captured patterns with `\\1` to "grab" them.

However, that doesn't appear to work in this example:

```
> gsub("([^-]+$)", "\\1", "xxx-yyy-zzz-abc")
[1] "xxx-yyy-zzz-abc"
```

The actual output is `xxx-yyy-zzz-abc` when I expected it to be `abc`. The regular expression above `([^-]+$)` captures the string after the last hyphen `-`, and I confirmed it here with this [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uCehD3/1).

Why isn't my output `abc`?

If I instead remove my captured pattern from the original string, everything works as expected, and `abc` is removed from original string.

```
> gsub("([^-]+$)", "", "xxx-yyy-zzz-abc")
[1] "xxx-yyy-zzz-"
```

What do I populate the code with below to get the output `abc`? And what went wrong?

```
> gsub("______", "______", "xxx-yyy-zzz-abc")
[1] "abc"
```

Comment: You *replace* matches with `gsub`. Use `regmatches` to *extract* ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23901600/3832970))

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew but in the question you reference there's an answer by @Ragy Isaac that seems to mimic my approach, which still leaves me wondering why my `gsub("([^-]+$)", "\\1", "xxx-yyy-zzz-abc")` doesn't functon as _I_ expect. @Ragy Isaac's solution to the example question was `gsub('([[:alpha:]]+)([0-9]+)([[:alpha:]]+)', '\\2', "aaa12xxx")` which does indeed behave as expected. The parenthesis `()` capture the string and the `\\2` spits it out. No?

Comment: It does not contradict the main idea: `gsub` / `sub` *replaces* matches. `[^-]+$` is a *matching* pattern since you want to get `abc` from `xxx-yyy-zzz-abc`. This answers your *Why isn't my output abc* question. If you want to use `gsub` to remove all unwanted parts of a string to get the part you want, go ahead.

Comment: You are matching only on the pattern you are replacing, which means the result will be the same. Match on the entire line instead: gsub(".*-([^-]+)$", "\\1", "xxx-yyy-zzz-abc")

Comment: @BigFinger I ended up using `gsub("^.*-", "", "xxx-yyy-zzz-abc")` but that's a great idea as well.